# Execute function while value of var is between 2 thresholds

Tags: python, python-3.5

I have a script that clean logs in a filesystem. I need that my code execute 2 functions (clean, checksize) inside a for with a list of directories. 
My problem is that i cant do the iterations between the two thresholds that i have defined.

This is my code:

```
count = 0
success = False

tmin = 90
tmax = 95

if (size > tmax):
    for directorio in directorios:
        count += 1
        if success:
            break
        for directorio in zip(*directorios[count - 1]):
            ruta = directorio[1]+'/builds/'
            if os.path.exists(ruta):
                flushdir(ruta)
                size = int(get_path_perc(path))
                print ("Has been removed: ", ruta)
            if (size <= tmin):
                success = True
                break
```

`Flushdir` is the function that delete directories and size is the function that check the free space. 
The actual result is that only execute the functions in the first `threshold(tmax)`, but not in `tmin` and i need that the functions execute in both thresholds..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be clear, you want to delete a directory whose size in between tmin and tmax (both inclusive) right?  And also, what is the value of size at first?

Comment: The value of size could be anyone. If value is over tmax, the code must execute. When the value is minor than tmax but over tmin, must execute. When size is minor than tmin, the script must finish.

Comment: Please give an example of possible value for `directorios`, I assume it is a list of directory names but cannot be sure, and since it is used as `zip` argument list, it is confusing. As a starting point I would suggest to give up the for loops and to use a `while size > tmin:` instead, I feel it could greatly simplify your code.

Comment: @Tryph posible value could be: /home/user/ for example.

Comment: Still not sure what this is supposed to do. As I understand it, when the count is higher than tmax, it should start a "cleanup", and clean up until the count is lower than tmin, right? If the count is between tmin and tmax it should not start a cleanup (but continue, if it is already cleaning)

Comment: No, the clean should be start when var 'size' is over than tmin and tmax. The problem in my code is that, the cleanup only is executing when is bigger than tmax, but not tmin...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing complex stuffs based on multiple `for` loops, variable setting and conditioned `break`, isn't it possible to do something more simple with a single `while`?

```py
tmin = 90
tmax = 95

size = int(get_path_perc(path))
if size > tmax:  # cleaning process needed
    index = 0  # starts at first directory...
    while size > tmin:  # ... until size is lower than `tmin`
        ruta = os.join(zip(*directorios[index])[1], 'builds')
        if os.path.exists(ruta):
            flushdir(ruta)
            size = int(get_path_perc(path))
            print ("Has been removed: ", ruta)
        index += 1  # consider next directory in next iteration
```

This is not tested and this `zip` call on `directorios` seems suspicious but not knowing what is in `directorios`, it is difficult to do better...